# System failure shortly after md raid growth and no md superblocks on added disks

Tags: linux, debian, raid

tl;dr; I tried to grow my raid array by adding 2 10 tb disks to an exsistant 4x4TB raid 5 array, had a failure with the system disk (not part of the raid) shortly after the growth finished and after recovering the system the new disks are not detectable as md volumes.

Question is: Is my data gone? If not how do I get the raid to discover the data on the 10TB drives?

Longer version:

I have a home NAS I have built on a debian system that was a 12TB array (4 4 TB drives with one drive worth of parity) using a software raid. It is encrypted with luks. I recenly bought 2 10TB disks to add to the array and followed the following steps (note that the disk labes change between this list and the next one):

1. `parted -s -a optimal /dev/sde mklabel gpt` # new disk 1 (this this step was proably not nessicary and may have actually messed me up)
2. `parted -s -a optimal /dev/sdg mklabel gpt` # new disk 2 (this this step was proably not nessicary and may have actually messed me up)
3. `parted /dev/sde`
4. 

```
    $ sudo parted /dev/sde
    GNU Parted 3.5
    Using /dev/sde
    Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
    (parted) print
    Model: ATA WDC WD101EFBX-68 (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sde: 10.0TB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
    Partition Table: gpt
    Disk Flags:
    
    Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags
    
    (parted) mkpart
    Partition name?  []? ext4
    File system type?  [ext2]? ext4
    Start? 1
    End? -1
    (parted) quit
    Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

5. Same for sdg
6. `sudo mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sde`
7. `sudo mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdg`
8. `sudo mdadm --grow --raid-devices=6 /dev/md0`
9. wait over a day
10. 

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md0 : active raid5 sdg[6] sde[5] sdf[2] sdb[0] sdd[4] sdc[1]
      11720659200 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 128k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [===============>.....]  reshape = 78.7% (3077233408/3906886400) finish=183.4min speed=75369K/sec
      bitmap: 0/30 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

11. wait overnite
12. 

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md0 : active raid5 sdg[6] sde[5] sdf[2] sdb[0] sdd[4] sdc[1]
      19534432000 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 128k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/30 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

13. come back to computer and getting kernel errors related to sata
14. panic
15. buy new hard drive
16. unplug all raid drives
17. install latest debian on new hard drive
18. shutdown, plug in raid drives
19. raid can't find super blocks on new (10 TB) drives

smartctrl examples:

```
root@nas2:/home/myusername# smartctl -i /dev/sde
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.0.0-5-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC7K0PT8X1X
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 266680715
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Dec  7 08:47:55 2022 MST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

root@nas2:/home/myusername# smartctl -i /dev/sdf
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.0.0-5-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD101EFBX-68B0AN0
Serial Number:    VHG5Y0DM
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 0c8c2b2c4
Firmware Version: 85.00A85
User Capacity:    10,000,831,348,736 bytes [10.0 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Dec  7 08:47:57 2022 MST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

root@nas2:/home/myusername#
```

mdadm examples:

```
root@nas2:/home/myusername# smartctl -i /dev/sdf
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.0.0-5-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD101EFBX-68B0AN0
Serial Number:    VHG5Y0DM
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 0c8c2b2c4
Firmware Version: 85.00A85
User Capacity:    10,000,831,348,736 bytes [10.0 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Dec  7 08:47:57 2022 MST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

root@nas2:/home/myusername# mdadm -E /dev/sde
/dev/sde:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 8fdcb089:a833ef1d:b160886d:412e7534
           Name : nas2:0  (local to host nas2)
  Creation Time : Sun Jun  2 07:39:33 2019
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813774256 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
     Array Size : 19534432000 KiB (18.19 TiB 20.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813772800 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 262912 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262832 sectors, after=1456 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 192d4876:e15d5e77:db7f147a:2691029b

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Dec  5 20:48:07 2022
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : a4b60d13 - correct
         Events : 171440

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
root@nas2:/home/myusername# mdadm -E /dev/sdf
/dev/sdf:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
root@nas2:/home/myusername# mdadm -E /dev/sdf1
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdf1.
root@nas2:/home/myusername#
```

dumpe2fs example:

```
root@nas2:/home/myusername# dumpe2fs /dev/sde
dumpe2fs 1.46.6-rc1 (12-Sep-2022)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sde
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
/dev/sde contains a linux_raid_member file system labelled 'nas2:0'
root@nas2:/home/myusername# dumpe2fs /dev/sdf
dumpe2fs 1.46.6-rc1 (12-Sep-2022)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdf
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdf
root@nas2:/home/myusername# dumpe2fs /dev/sdf1
dumpe2fs 1.46.6-rc1 (12-Sep-2022)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdf1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

/proc/mdstat:

```
root@nas2:/home/myusername# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md127 : inactive sda[1](S) sdc[4](S) sde[2](S) sdb[0](S)
      15627548512 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>`

mdadm -d:
`root@nas2:/home/myusername# mdadm -D /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid5
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 4

              Name : nas2:0  (local to host nas2)
              UUID : 8fdcb089:a833ef1d:b160886d:412e7534
            Events : 171440

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       64        -        /dev/sde
       -       8       32        -        /dev/sdc
       -       8        0        -        /dev/sda
       -       8       16        -        /dev/sdb
```

mdadm.conf:

```
root@nas2:/home/myusername# cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
# mdadm.conf
#
# !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
# !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers
DEVICE /dev/sd[abcdef]
DEVICE /dev/sd[abcdef]1
DEVICE partitions
# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This configuration was auto-generated on Tue, 06 Dec 2022 20:18:27 -0700 by mkconf
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=8fdcb089:a833ef1d:b160886d:412e7534 name=nas2:0
```

attempting to start the array:

```
root@nas2:/home/myusername# mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sde
mdadm: /dev/sda is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdb is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdc is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sde is busy - skipping
root@nas2:/home/myusername# mdadm --stop /dev/md127
mdadm: stopped /dev/md127
root@nas2:/home/myusername# mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sde
mdadm: /dev/md127 assembled from 4 drives - not enough to start the array.
root@nas2:/home/myusername# mdadm --stop /dev/md127
mdadm: error opening /dev/md127: No such file or directory
root@nas2:/home/myusername# mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sde /dev/sdd /dev/sdf
mdadm: /dev/sda is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdb is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdc is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sde is busy - skipping
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdd
mdadm: /dev/sdd has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

lsblk output

```
root@nas2:/home/myusername# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0   3.6T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0     0B  0 md
sdb           8:16   0   3.6T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0     0B  0 md
sdc           8:32   0   3.6T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0     0B  0 md
sdd           8:48   0   9.1T  0 disk
└─sdd1        8:49   0   9.1T  0 part
sde           8:64   0   3.6T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0     0B  0 md
sdf           8:80   0   9.1T  0 disk
└─sdf1        8:81   0   9.1T  0 part
nvme0n1     259:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   1.9G  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 201.7G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  18.6G  0 part /var
├─nvme0n1p5 259:4    0    10M  0 part /tmp
└─nvme0n1p6 259:5    0 243.5G  0 part /home
```

Comment: Your data is likely fine.  It would seem more of an issue correctly identifying and mounting the disks then anything else.  What does **lsblk** output ?  (I wonder if you have a disk /dev/sdg or /dev/sdh which is not listed in mdadm.conf  (the DEVICE line only goes up to sdf).

Comment: How about backing up /etc/mdadm.conf, and then commenting out the DEVICE lines altogether?  I **think** this will scan all partititions.

Comment: @davidgo I added lsblock, from what I can tell the raid said it did stuff to the 10tb disks but then never wrote the superblocks?

Comment: I see what you mean.  Ouch.

Comment: This is way past my pay grade, so not a recommendation - but have you seen https://kevin.deldycke.com/2007/03/how-to-recover-a-raid-array-after-having-zero-ized-superblocks/  - **It looks to be extremely high risk**, but I wonder if it could work for you?

Comment: @davidgo that is the kind of thing I'm looking for, you're right it's mega-risky but it may be what I need to do.